# Marginal and conditional density for $f_{XY}(x,y)=24xy1_{\{x>0,y>0,x+y\leq1\}}$

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, marginal-distribution

$f_{XY}(x,y)=24xy1_{\{x>0,y>0,x+y\leq1\}}$

$1_{\{...\}}$ is the indicator function

> I am not sure how to apply the conditions ${\{x>0,y>0,x+y\leq1\}}$ when evaluating $f_X(x)$, $f_Y(y)$ and $f_{X|Y}(x,y)$, meaning I don't know which bounds I have to use for $f_X, f_Y$ and $f_{X|Y}$

(I need it to determine $\mathbb E(X)$, $\mathbb E(Y)$ and $\mathbb E(X|Y)$)

I tried the following

$f_X(x)=\int f_{XY}(x,y)dy=\int_0^{1-x}24xydy$ for $0<x<1$ and $f_X(x)=0$ otherwise.

$f_Y(y)=\int f_{XY}(x,y)dx=\int_0^{1-x}24xydx$ for $0<y<1$ and $f_Y(y)=0$ otherwise.

$f_{X|Y}(x,y)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}=\frac{2x}{(y-1)^2}1_{\{???\}}$

Comment: In your $f_X(x)$ you presumably want the integral $\int_0^{1-y}$

Comment: In your $f_{X\mid Y}$ you presumably want the indicator something like $1_{\{0 \lt x \lt 1-y\lt 1\}}$